# Getting retun value of function object in jScript

Tags: function, object, jscript

I have a **j Script** function like below

```
function a(){
\\ do something
if (X=y){
  \\do other things
   {
else {
  return false
   }
//Do final things
return true
}
```

then I call that

```
function b(){
var P = new a();
log p.valueOf() //this always equal to 'object object'

}
```

Can some body please help me on how to get return value of function a() within b()

Comment: With the code you've provided, just do `var p = a();`.  JavaScript is case sensitive (`P != p`).  Also, you don't call `new` on a function-- that would turn the function into a javascript *class* and create a new instance.  If this doesn't answer your question or fix your problem, it's because you didn't give us a large enough code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do in function `b()` is evaluate function `a()` and log its value, you don't need var `p`. `valueOf()` does not evaluate a function, and declaring `p = new a();` does not make `p` a function. [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf)

Just evaluate `a()`, and store its result in p. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/birdyinc/j27hr/8/):

```
function b(){
    var p = a();
    console.log(p); //should output `true` or `false`
}
```